# how to show video pop up in dialog

Tags: android

here i am doing code that when i click on show video button it should open a dialog box where we can run video of any size. below is my source code

source code is:-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private Button videoView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initViews();
}


private void initViews() {
            buttonvideoView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_videoview);
                    String STREAM_URL = "http://videofry.com/mp4/34822/Yaar_Bathere-Alfaaz(VideoFRY.Com).mp4";
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(STREAM_URL);
                    VideoView mVideo = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
                    mVideo.setVideoURI(uri);
                    MediaController controller = new MediaController(MainActivity.this);
                    controller.setAnchorView(mVideo);
                    mVideo.setKeepScreenOn(true);
                    mVideo.setMediaController(controller);

                    mVideo.start();
                    dialog.show();
                }

    videoView = (Button)findViewById(R.id.video_videw);
    videoView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, VideoActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

 }
```

i tried lots of trick but it didnt help. it showing null pointer exception. if u suggest any other method for running video in dialog box then that should be also highly appreciated.

```
04-08 11:50:17.630: E/AndroidRuntime(1058): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-08 11:50:17.630: E/AndroidRuntime(1058): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-08 11:50:17.630: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at    com.example.sampletest.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:37)
04-08 11:50:17.630: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3480)
04-08 11:50:17.630: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13983)
04-08 11:50:17.630: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
04-08 11:50:17.630: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-08 11:50:17.630: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-08 11:50:17.630: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
04-08 11:50:17.630: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-08 11:50:17.630: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-08 11:50:17.630: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-08 11:50:17.630: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-08 11:50:17.630: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Where does it shows nullpointerexception? Can you share the stack trace?

Comment: @Avinash - post your logcat output

Comment: i have added logcat output

Comment: @Avinash - VideoView mVideo = (VideoView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.videoView);